# applying a function on an object in python

Tags: python, class, artificial-life

I wrote an artificial life simulation. each creature is an object of the class "Animal" that i defined, with some properties. I defined a function "reproduce" outside the Animal class:

```
def reproduce(parent):
    child = Animal()
    child.brain.w= parent.brain.w[:]
    child.brain.ix= parent.brain.ix[:]
    child.x,child.y = random.randint(0,width),random.randint(0,height)
    child.age = 0
    child.fitness= 9 + parent.fitness/10 #parent.fitness/2

    mutation = random.choice([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5])
    for b in range(mutation):
      child.brain.mutate()
    animals.append(child)
```

As can be seen, each animal has a brain, which is an object from different class: for each animal I defined `animals[i].brain = Brain()`. the "mutate" part in the reproduce function ensures that the child's brain is not identical to the parent's brain.

However, the problem is that when I apply this function on some animal from the list, the child indeed get slightly new brain, but the parent's brain becomes identical to the child's new brain. When I use `reproduce(copy.deepcopy(animals[i]))` instead of `reproduce(animals[i])` that does not happen. What is the reason?

Comment: I think you've going to need to post the code for `Animal`.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe `brain.w` or `brain.ix` is a list of lists?  Then `w[:]` gives you one new list that still contains the same old sublists.

Comment: using [:] should make a copy of the parent brain. Can you post more code? Personally, I would make reproduce() a method of the Animal class.

Comment: My first stab at fixing this would be to replace the two lines assigning to `child.brain.w` and `child.brain.ix` with the single assignment `child.brain = copy.deepcopy(parent.brain)`.  In fact, I'd like to know why you don't simply replace the first three lines of your function with `child = copy.deepcopy(parent)`.

Comment: Without more info, we're really fishing in the dark. My [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15180841/709852) is a stab at an area where this sort of problem crops up, but I can't get the deepcopy bit.

Comment: Armin Rigo, can you be more specific please? indeed brain.w and brain.ix are list of lists, but why should it make this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another stab based on @Armin's comment. This *does* exhibit the relevant deepcopy behaviour:

```
import random

width = 5
height = 5

class Brain(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.w = [[1]]
        self.ix = [[1]]

    def mutate(self):
        self.w[0].append(1)

class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.brain = Brain()
        self.x = random.randint(0, width)
        self.y = random.randint(0, height)
        self.age = 0
        self.fitness = 10

def reproduce(parent):
    child = Animal()
    child.brain.w= parent.brain.w[:]
    child.brain.ix= parent.brain.ix[:]
    child.x,child.y = random.randint(0,width),random.randint(0,height)
    child.age = 0
    child.fitness= 9 + parent.fitness/10 #parent.fitness/2

    mutation = random.choice([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5])
    for b in range(mutation):
      child.brain.mutate()
    animals.append(child)

animals = []
parent = Animal()

animals.append(parent)
print parent.brain.w
#reproduce(parent)
import copy
reproduce(copy.deepcopy(parent))

for each in animals:
    print each.brain.w
```

The fix here is to not have the state values stored in a mutable type that you're copying between objects; in this case a list, but it could be any mutable object.

Edit:
What you're doing in the original code is to copy the contents of `parent.brain.w` into `child.brain.w`. Python has the property that assignments are to the original object, not copies of the object or the contents (unless you use the `copy` module). [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) cover this well. Tersely, this means the following is true:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> b = a
>>> b.append(6)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a is b
True
```

That is, both `a` and `b` are the same list. That isn't quite what you are doing; you're copying a list into an object, but that is equivalent:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3]]
>>> b = []
>>> b = a[:] # What you are doing
>>> b is a
False
>>> b[0] is a[0]
True
>>> b[0].append(4)
>>> b[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a[0]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

If your type is not mutable, then when you modify it, a new object is created. Consider, for example, a somewhat equivalent list of tuples (which are immutable):

```
>>> a = [(1, 2, 3)]
>>> b = []
>>> b = a[:]
>>> b is a
False
>>> b[0] is a[0] # Initially the objects are the same
True
>>> b[0] += (4,) # Now a new object is created and overwrites b[0]
>>> b[0] is a[0]
False
>>> b[0]
(1, 2, 3, 4)
>>> a[0]
(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: THank you for the answer. I think you found the problem. But why can't I store the state as a list of lists? why there is a problem with copying such a list?

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Contrary to the initial assertion, the following doesn't exhibit the deepcopy behaviour which I missed in the description. Still, I'll leave it up in case there is anything useful.

A bit of a guess, but the following exhibits the behaviour you are encountering:

```
import random

width = 5
height = 5

class Brain(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.w = [1]
        self.ix = [1]
        self.state = 1

    def mutate(self):
        self.state += 1

class Animal(object):
    brain = Brain()
    x = random.randint(0, width)
    y = random.randint(0,height)
    age = 0
    fitness = 10

def reproduce(parent):
    child = Animal()
    child.brain.w= parent.brain.w[:]
    child.brain.ix= parent.brain.ix[:]
    child.x,child.y = random.randint(0,width),random.randint(0,height)
    child.age = 0
    child.fitness= 9 + parent.fitness/10 #parent.fitness/2

    mutation = random.choice([0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5])
    for b in range(mutation):
      child.brain.mutate()
    animals.append(child)

animals = []
parent = Animal()

animals.append(parent)
print parent.brain.state
reproduce(parent)

for each in animals:
    print each.brain.state
```

When you run it, you get out:

```
1
2
2
```

If this is the case, the problem is because `animal.brain` is an attribute of the class, not the instance. The consequence of this is that all instances share the attribute.

It's simple to correct:

```
class Animal(object):
    x = random.randint(0, width)
    y = random.randint(0,height)
    age = 0
    fitness = 10

    def __init__(self):
        self.brain = Brain()
```

With that fix, you'll output the correct value for the parent, and the child will change. For example:

```
1
1
3
```

(according to how many times `mutate()` is called).

You'll also likely encounter similar problems with the other properties of `Brain`, but that can be an exercise for the reader.